# How to implement an adaptive loss in Keras?

Tags: keras, callback, loss

I am trying to use Keras to implement the work done in [**A General and Adaptive Robust Loss Function**](https://arxiv.org/abs/1701.03077). The author provides tensorflow code that works the hard details. I am just trying to use his prebuilt function in Keras.

His custom loss function is learning a parameter 'alpha' that controls the shape of the loss function. I would like to track 'alpha' in addition to the loss during training.

I am somewhat familiar with Keras custom loss functions and using wrappers, but I am not entirely sure how to use callbacks to track 'alpha'. Below is how I would choose to naively construct the loss function in Keras. However I am not sure how I would then access the 'alpha' to track.

[From the provided tensorflow code](https://github.com/google-research/google-research/blob/master/robust_loss/adaptive.py), the function lossfun(x) returns a tuple.

```py
def lossfun(x,
            alpha_lo=0.001,
            alpha_hi=1.999,
            alpha_init=None,
            scale_lo=1e-5,
            scale_init=1.,
            **kwargs):
    """
    Returns:
        A tuple of the form (`loss`, `alpha`, `scale`).
    """
```

```py
def customAdaptiveLoss(): 
    def wrappedloss(y_true,y_pred):
        loss, alpha, scale = lossfun((y_true-y_pred))  #Author's function
        return loss
    return wrappedloss
```

```py
Model.compile(optimizer = optimizers.Adam(0.001),
                        loss = customAdaptiveLoss,)
```

Again, what I am hoping to do is track the variable 'alpha' during training.

Comment: Suggestion: Add a custom metric that accesses the same object that you use for the customAdaptiveLoss. You can save alpha in that object and print it in your metric. The hard part is that this must be tensors not python values. i.e. define a K.variable which you should update when computing the loss and then use the result in the custom metric. It may be a bit tricky but should be doable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following example displays alpha as a metric. Tested in colab.

```
%%
!git clone https://github.com/google-research/google-research.git

%%
import sys
sys.path.append('google-research')
from robust_loss.adaptive import lossfun

# the robust_loss impl depends on the current workdir to load a data file.
import os
os.chdir('google-research')

import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras
from tensorflow.keras.layers import *
from tensorflow.keras.models import Model
from tensorflow.keras import backend as K

class RobustAdaptativeLoss(object):
  def __init__(self):
    z = np.array([[0]])
    self.v_alpha = K.variable(z)

  def loss(self, y_true, y_pred, **kwargs):
    x = y_true - y_pred
    x = K.reshape(x, shape=(-1, 1))
    with tf.variable_scope("lossfun", reuse=True):
      loss, alpha, scale = lossfun(x)
    op = K.update(self.v_alpha, alpha)
    # The alpha update must be part of the graph but it should
    # not influence the result.
    return loss + 0 * op

  def alpha(self, y_true, y_pred):
    return self.v_alpha

def make_model():
  inp = Input(shape=(3,))
  out = Dense(1, use_bias=False)(inp)
  model = Model(inp, out)
  loss = RobustAdaptativeLoss()
  model.compile('adam', loss.loss, metrics=[loss.alpha])
  return model

model = make_model()
model.summary()

init_op = tf.global_variables_initializer()
K.get_session().run(init_op)

import numpy as np

FACTORS = np.array([0.5, 2.0, 5.0])
def target_fn(x):
  return np.dot(x, FACTORS.T)

N_SAMPLES=100
X = np.random.rand(N_SAMPLES, 3)
Y = np.apply_along_axis(target_fn, 1, X)

history = model.fit(X, Y, epochs=2, verbose=True)
print('final loss:', history.history['loss'][-1])
```

Comment: That is very helpful, however when I run the code in Spyder I get the following error: `ValueError: Variable lossfun/LatentAlpha does not exist, or was not created with tf.get_variable(). Did you mean to set reuse=tf.AUTO_REUSE in VarScope?`

Comment: It seems I had a mistake in my environment setup. The code you provided works as posted. Interestingly alpha seems to converges to 1.000 after a short time in both of the examples I have played with. I will try some others and update.

Comment: Something does seem to be wrong. Here is a simple [example](https://gist.github.com/Nmerrillvt/d1a8187bff69cd5a85af26deee234633). The alpha converges to 1, but an alpha of 0.4 shows a better solution.This is well beyond the scope of the original question, but I thought I would share.

Comment: @NickMerrill how to you resolve your ValueError? I'm having the same issue. Can't get it to run

Comment: @ClimbingTheCurve I’m sorry to say that I never figured it out

Comment: Oh, your second comment made it seem like you had worked it out.

Comment: I feel stupid...
I switched from `with tf.variable_scope("lossfun", reuse=True):` to `with tf.variable_scope("lossfun", reuse=tf.AUTO_REUSE):` and it worked fine

Comment: @ClimbingTheCurve I've since switched over to tf 2.0 so now going back is a pain, I've updated the above link, but I am getting: ```line 179, in lossfun
    latent_alpha = tf.compat.v1.get_variable(#tf.compat.v1.get_variable(

AttributeError: module 'tensorflow_core.compat.v1.compat' has no attribute 'v1'``` Did you run into this?